# Having an error while compiling a Rollkit on Linux for a blockchain built on Cosmos

Tags: go, blockchain, cosmos-sdk

I'm just learning and stuck in the middle of process.

While compiling, one document marks this error:

```
✘ File: /root/minibar/proto/minibar/minibar/query.proto: <input>:21:3: found "message" but expected [service comment|rpc]
```

The file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package minibar.minibar;

import "gogoproto/gogo.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "cosmos/base/query/v1beta1/pagination.proto";
import "minibar/minibar/params.proto";

option go_package = "minibar/x/minibar/types";

// Query defines the gRPC querier service.
service Query {

// Parameters queries the parameters of the module.
rpc Params (QueryParamsRequest) returns (QueryParamsResponse) {
option (google.api.http).get = "/minibar/minibar/params";
}

// QueryParamsResponse is response type for the Query/Params RPC method.
message QueryParamsResponse {

// params holds all the parameters of this module.
Params params = 1 \[(gogoproto.nullable) = false\];
}

message QueryUnitsRequest {}

message QueryUnitsResponse {
string alcotype = 1;
string country  = 2;
string name     = 3;
string volume   = 4;
}
```

Would appreciate any help You can provide.

Been trying different approaches, but it went beyond my knowledge.